# How to show that f(x) = x is uniformly continuous on R

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I need some help on a problem. In my real analysis class, we have just been introduced to the idea of uniform continuity. While I know how to show that $\mathit{f(x) = x}$ is continuous, I need some help showing that $\mathit{f(x) = x }$is uniformly continuous. Would someone mind taking a look at what I have done so far? Thanks in advance.

So far this is what I have:

> Let $\mathit{f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}}$, $\mathit{S}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$,
> be defined by $\mathit{f(x)=x}$.
>
> Then, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall$
> $x_{0}$ $\in \mathit{S}$ and $\forall$ x $\in \mathit{S}$ such that
> |$\mathit{x} - \mathit{x_{0}}$| $\Rightarrow$ |$\mathit{f(x)} -
> \mathit{f(x_{0})}$|.
>
> Thus, we can conclude that $\mathit{f(x) = x}$ is uniformly
> continuous.

I went back and worked through this again with the comments below in mind. How does this look?

> Let $\mathit{f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}}$,
> $\mathit{S}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, be defined by $\mathit{f(x)=x}$.
>
> We know that for $\mathit{f}$ to be continuous, then $\forall \epsilon
> > 0$,  $\exists \delta > 0$ such that if  $x_{0}$ and $\mathit{x}$ $\in \mathit{S}$ and  |$\mathit{x} - \mathit{x_{0}}$| < $\epsilon$,
> |$\mathit{f(x)} - \mathit{f(x_{0})}$| < $\delta$ must hold.
>
> Let $\epsilon$ = $\delta$.
>
> Then, whenever |$\mathit{x} - \mathit{x_{0}}$| < $\delta$, then
> |$\mathit{f(x)} - \mathit{f(x_{0})}$| < $\epsilon$ = $\delta$.
>
> Thus, $\mathit{f(x)=x}$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof seems like you have the right idea, but just needs a little better wording.

Indeed, $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, there does exist a $\delta$. In fact, you should say that we choose $\delta = \varepsilon$. This choice of delta thus does not depend on the values $x,x_0\in S$ that you choose.

Then we see that whenever $|x-x_0|<\varepsilon$, we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|x-x_0|<\varepsilon=\delta$.

Comment: Ah I understand. So what I need to do is chest set  = ? Thanks for the help. That makes more sense.